# Output any string input with Prolog

Tags: io, prolog

Checking to see if it's possible to format a string reliably with base model prolog(no modules). I have the following code that I thought would work but doesn't:

```
hello(_) :-
  write('\nEnter Name: '),
  read(Name),
  format('\nThe name you entered is: ~s', [Name]).
```

This throws the error if the user entered `Bob.` but works if the user entered `"Bob".` or `'Bob'.`

```
ERROR: format/2: Illegal argument to format sequence ~s: _G7118
```

I have also tried replacing the format with `writeq` like:

```
hello(_) :-
  write('\nEnter Name: '),
  read(Name),
  writeq(Name).
```

Which doesn't thrown an error but does just end up printing `_L143` instead of `Bob`

Comment: Why do you have a nameless argument for `hello`? You can just have `hello :-...`. Regarding your error, `read/1` expects a Prolog term to be input. So when you enter `Bob` without quotes, Prolog sees it as a term, which is a variable in this case. The `format` is expecting an atom but seeing a variable. `writeq` will write it as a namless variable, `_L143`. The quotes around `Bob` make it an atom, which is what you are wanting to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

Don't use `read` like this, as @lurker explains, it is not for entering "strings" or "text" or answers to questions altogether. Before even going down this road, ask yourself: "Why?"

The Prolog top level is your interactive command line prompt. It is not like in C or any other compiled language where you need to actually make your interpreter.

So, your `hello/1` could look like this:

```
hello(Name) :-
    format("~w~n", [Name]).
```

You still need to say `hello("Bob")` or `hello('Bob')` from the prompt, of course.

If you want to make your own interpreter on top of the Prolog top level, this is another thing altogether.

Answer (score -1):

As other have said, `read/1` reads only valid Prolog syntax. To read an arbitrary line of text using standard Prolog primitives, you would have to read the input character by character:

```
read_line(Cs) :-
    get_code(C),
    ( C == 0'\n -> Cs = []     % end of line
    ; C == -1   -> Cs = []     % end of input
    ; Cs = [C|Cs1], read_line(Cs1)
    ).
```

As you are using SWI-Prolog, indicated by your use of format/2 and the (deleted by others) SWI-Prolog tag, you can also use

```
read_line(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_string(Input, "\n", "\r", End, String).
```

Other systems have the same or similar predicates, but they are not standardized.

Comment: For SWI-Prolog, there is also `read_line_to_codes/2`, along with other useful predicates in [`library(readutil)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=readutil).

Comment: I have not downvoted this, but it does seem a bit 1970-style to do it this way. One reason I can only recommend against this is that this way of doing I/O is very hard to test with unit tests. If you really want to read a line, do it with DCGs and use `library(pio)` in SICStus and SWI to then apply the DCG to a file or stream. This is very efficient (internally, it reads characters in chunks instead of doing it one-by-one) and can be much more easily tested also with unit tests. In this case, OP's acceptance of the other answer also hints that this is not at all what is actually needed here.

Comment: @mat `?- phrase_from_stream(line(L), user_input).
ERROR: set_stream_position/2: No permission to reposition stream user_input`. It just doesn't work. `read_line_to_codes(user_input, Line)` works, as well as the solution in this answer.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunately still the case. I wish more people were interested in contributing to this library.